# How to install R in a RedHat server without internet connection

Tags: r, linux, server, redhat

I want to install R in a RedHat machine but this machine is not allowed to access to internet due to security issues. I have searched a solution but best answer that I have found is installing it in another RedHat machine and copy&paste the packages. The problem is that I don't have another machine with this OS.

I have found this solution http://www.bigdatafarm.com/?p=426 but I am not sure that it is the correct solution because the step of mounting the r_repo (sudo mount -t /root/r_repo/* /mnt/r_src) doesn't work.

I don't have much experience in RedHat and every help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: doesnt RedHat have a USB?

Comment: Your best bet is to install R from source. It can be easy/hard depending on your expertise and on the amount of external OS-libraries you need to install on the system, since installing R from source requires a bunch of libraries to be properly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download RPM package from repository ( https://www.rpmfind.net/ ) and all dependencies. Use scp or pendrive to copy files on machine.

To install package use command:

```
rpm --install nameOfPackage.rpm
```